# Making element of list first,jquery :eq ,index

Tags: jquery, list, slider

I have a moving-list.

```
<li class="class1">1</li>    
<li class="class2">2</li>    
<li class="class3">3</li>
```

And i got two buttons. Its slider so when you click navigation arrow list will look like this:

```
<li class="class2">2</li>    
<li class="class3">3</li>    
<li class="class1">1</li>
```

Im using `$("li:eq(1)").before($("li:eq(2)"));`

But i have 3 new navigation buttons,everyone should move the selected item as the first on the list
Onclick button 3:

```
<li class="class3">3</li>    
<li class="class2">2</li>    
<li class="class1">1</li>
```

I cant do it. Replace didnt worked for me. I just need to make element as the first on the list ,but i cant modify the :eq. Can you help please?

Comment: Its a slider,and user can see only first element of list. I want to show user the element which one he will choose by button. If he will click on button 3 i want to move <li class="class3">3</li> to the first position on list

Comment: When 3 is clicked, 3 must go to the top, what about 1 and 2?

Comment: They have to move backward to second andd third position

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to base your logic entirely off of position, since it can change.  You will want to target another identifier, such as the classes you are using.

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $('.goToSlide').on('click', function(){
    var recordClass = '.class'+ $(this).data('record');
    
    $('.slides').prepend($(recordClass));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="slides">
  <li class="class1">1</li>
  <li class="class2">2</li>
  <li class="class3">3</li>
</ul>
<button class="goToSlide" data-record="1">1</button>
<button class="goToSlide" data-record="2">2</button>
<button class="goToSlide" data-record="3">3</button>
```